# Which chess pro's are in esports organizations?

Tags: online-chess, streaming, botez

All I got so far:

1. Alex & Andrea Botez - Envy
2. Hikaru Nakamura - TSM (team solomid)
3. Andrew Tang (Penguingm1) - C9 (cloud9)
4. Nemo Zhou Qiyu (akanemsko) - CLG (Counter Logic Gaming)

Is there some kind of list for this please? (Besides perhaps doing [category intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Category_intersection) on wiki, if it will even give me a complete list, at least with the ones who have wiki pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anna Cramling. From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Cramling):

> After about a year of streaming on Twitch, she signed with Panda, becoming their first chess streamer as well as the first Swedish chess player to sign with an eSports organisation.