# Why did Andrea Botez ask Magnus Carlsen “How does the knight move?” after a game in the 2021 World Chess Championship?

Tags: world-championship, knights, carlsen, botez

[Andrea Botez](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/which-chess-pros-are-in-esports-organizations) asked world chess champion Magnus Carlsen [“How does the knight move?” in a press conference](https://youtu.be/wfDCLEAU9hE?t=13) after a game in the 2021 World Chess Championship. It seems like such an obvious question that it must be a joke of some kind. What’s going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

During one of the Botez streams, Magnus jokingly asked how the knight moves. Andrea explains in her recent [YouTube video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=jRE-x-V8PZk).

To answer your question: yes, it is a joke!